# Recommend automated night ftp backups for windows machine

Tags: backup, ftp

My web server was messed up and the host only has a 1 night archive. It took me a day to find the problem so my backup is no help.

In order to avoid this in the future I am going to do a nightly backup, but I need a recommendation of some free software to run on windows that will do a backup via ftp.

Answer (score 1):

a batch file running as a scheduled task will do this for you:

```
rem ### get files from a remote folder

> ftp.do echo o ftp.site.net
>> ftp.do echo <user>
>> ftp.do echo <pass>
>> ftp.do echo cd /folder/
>> ftp.do echo prompt
>> ftp.do echo mget *
>> ftp.do echo bye 
ftp -s:ftp.do 
del ftp.do
```

if you need something more than this then your needs are probably more specific, in which case more detail on your question wouldn't hurt :)

if you want to use this in a 'push' scenario on the server with the backups then just swap mget with mput

Answer (score 0):

[Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) does what you want. It support Full/Incremental/Differential backups, keeping multiple timestamped copies, destinations that can be Local/Samba/FTP, full logging (with the option to email the log to you after backups), and encryption (because FTP isn't secure).

Answer (score 0):

It's not being supported anymore but i use Restore from http://sourceforge.net/projects/restore

does sftp, ftp, SAMBA  and mysql backups along with revisions / schedules

can delegate to users etc
and all is done via web UI  :)